# Automatic calculation responsive images from sprite with Less mixins

Tags: html, css, less

Could anybody advise me a collection of less mixins for automatic calculation CSS properties for responsive images from sprite? I need a result code like this:

> background-image: url();
>
> background-position: % %;
>
> background-size: % %;
>
> padding-top: % %;
>
> width: %;

I know how to calculate it manually, but it takes a long time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [**resprite-less**](https://github.com/alsemenovv/resprite-less) can help you.

#### Example:

[image]

Initial data:

1. spr-url = "../img/spr.png"
2. spr-width = 382px
3. spr-height = 556px
4. img1-width = 322px
5. img1-height = 238px
6. x1 = 40px
7. y1 = 42px

HTML:

```
    <!--Any parent container-->
    <div class="container">
        <!--Responsive background image element-->
        <div class="img1"></div>
    </div>
```

Less:

```
    .img1 {
        .rs("../img/spr.png", 382, 556, 322, 238, 40, 42);
    }
```

The code above resprite.less will compile to such CSS code:

```
    .img1 {
        background: url("../img/spr.png") 66.67% 13.21%;
        background-size: 118.63% 233.61%;
        padding-top: 73.91%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

[Demo](http://webtricks.alsemenov.com/code/resprite-less/basics.html)